# Only ASPX (HTML) file run through virtual directory but when connect to database it doesn't find web.config connection

Tags: asp.net

Only ASPX (HTML) file run through virtual directory but when connect to database it doesn't find web.config connection.My code..

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="ugs" value="data source=192.168.0.235\SQLEXPRESS,80; Persist Security Info=True; initial catalog=ugs_academy; integrated security=true;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you need to put the information in the connectionStrings element.
[Read more on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this link,  [how to get the value from AppSetttings](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article80.aspx) and also you cand read an excellent article for appsettings [AppSettings](http://odetocode.com/Articles/345.aspx)

```
string ConnStr= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ugs"].ToString();
```

then later you pass this Connection string to your SqlConnection class open.

```
using(SqlConnection connObj = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
{ 
   //do some thing with ConnObj. 
}
```